# Draw line in table view cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can i draw a inside table cell so that i can place 2 controls in same cell with separator. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use a UIImageView myself. However, here is someone else who wants to know how to draw a line too:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3238-how-draw-simple-line.html

Comment: How can I use UIImageView? Can u explain me.

Comment: I'd copy the table as it is now to an image (simply ctrl+3 or something), and then see where the line should be in any simple image editor. Then, save just your line and the white area around it (as large as the cell) to a file, and set it as a background image for the cell (http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23505-uitableviewcell-background-image.html).